# Como zerar a hora e diminuir um dia de um DATETIME?

Tags: php, datetime

Eu tenho um campo `DATETIME` que eu pego do SQL, formato `YYYY-mm-dd H-m-s` e preciso zerar a hora e diminuir um dia.

Eu estou conseguindo diminuir um dia utilizando `date_modify($date, '-1 day');`, mas como zerar a hora?

Comment: tem 3 ótimas resposta e não acredito que nenhuma delas serviu para você, por favor se você acho alguma resposta boa abaixo marca-la como certo ou dar um upvote :) Obrigado

Comment: Certo. Eu acabei fazendo de outra maneira, votei na que mais me ajudou. Vou postar minha solução, talvez ajude alguém.

Comment: Ok, obrigado :)

Comment: @MagisterMundus inclusive você pode aceitar a sua própria resposta, se foi a que mais ajudou.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tente o seguinte código:

```
$date = date_create('2000-01-20 01:00:00');
date_sub($date, date_interval_create_from_date_string('1 days'));
echo date_format($date, 'Y-m-d');
```

<sub>Resposta baseada no [primeiro exemplo da documentação para `DateTime::sub -- date_sub`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.sub.php).</sub>

Answer (score 2):

Isso aqui já resolve:

```
<?php echo date("Y-m-d", strtotime("2014-03-27" . " - 1 days")); ?>
```

Sendo que "2014-03-27" é a sua data em específico.

Você pode colocar a hora estática no sua data customizada para "zerar": "2014-03-27 00:00:00"

Comment: Sim, mas acredito que ele disse diminuir um dia e não aumentar um dia, mas fora isso boa resposta.

Comment: Confundi o sinal, já vou editar minha resposta para melhor compreenção.

Answer (score 0):

Supondo que você esteja utilizando MySQL, tente diretamente na expressão SQL:

```
SELECT CAST(seu_campo AS DATE) - INTERVAL 1 DAY;
```

Answer (score 0):

Acabei fazendo assim:

```
//Gerando um datetime $data novo para nao ter que colocar a parte do SQL
$data = new DateTime('2014-03-21 23:50:10');
$dia_anterior_hora_zerada = new DateTime();
$dia_anterior_hora_zerada = $data;
$dia_anterior_hora_zerada->setTime(00,00,00);
$dia_anterior_hora_zerada->modify('-1 day');
//$dia_anterior_hora_zerada = "2014-03-20 00:00:00"
```